# Эквивалент английского cheesy?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

Вот одно из определений слова cheesy из [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheesy):

> This is an important word and nobody has it right yet. What it means is: Trying too hard, unsubtle, and inauthentic. 
>   Specifically that which is unsubtle or inauthentic in its way of trying to elicit a certain response from a viewer, listener, audience, etc. Celine Dion is cheesy because her lyrics, timbre, key changes, and swelling orchestral accompaniment telegraph 'i want you to be moved' instead of moving you. Gold chains on an exposed hairy chest are cheesy because they shout out: "I have money and I am manly" instead of impressing a woman in a more subtle way, or allowing a woman to form her own judgments. The excessive showing off suggests he's compensating for what he does not have--i.e., he's actually poor, insecure, or short with an inferiority complex. Cliches are often cheesy because they are an obvious and artless way of making a point. A movie might be cheesy if it contains 'on the nose' dialogue, like "I can't live without you" or "You had me at hello."

Надеюсь, переводить не надо. Если надо, намекните, переведу :)

Есть ли в русском языке эквивалентное прилагательное?

Comment: When trying to translate something, please always add some context. In its current form, your question is not just a translation request (which is offtopic), but a translation request without context. Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi: I have specifically chosen the rather vivid definition from urban dictionary because it provides all the usual contexts the word is used in. Since it's a slang word, its translation is not available in the dictionaries I am aware. Hence, I believe the question is on topic.

Comment: sure, but you still better provide some context to clarify which of these meanings you need. Celine Dion is *китчевая*, the gold chain is *безвкусная*, cliches are *избитые* and the movie dialogs are *пошлые*.

Comment: @Quassnoi, well, actually I was hoping for a word that would encompass all of the above. It's a really handy word I haven't found an equivalent for in other languages.

Comment: "Жлобский" can encompass all of the above, but it has negative connotations. That is why the context is needed, it would let us know if such connotations in the translation are acceptible for you. Is "cheesy" an offensive word?

Comment: Cheesy has a negative connotation in any context. It describes someone or something that is "over the top" to varying degrees - usually for effect. For example a salesperson who smiles too much and uses a forced laugh and flattery exemplifies cheesiness. A performer who resorts to all the performance clichés - bombastic costumes, overly dramatic gestures, etc. The premise is that you can take anything plain and put cheese on it and make it more appealing - but it doesn't always work. Since it implies so many different nuances of exaggeration, I can't imagine summing it up in one word in Rus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попсовый это очень хороший вариант он молодежный, сленговый, "на слуху", может относиться и к кино, к книгам, живописи и т.п. Но мне кажется что в случае музыки это определение довольно расплывчато, т.к. обозначает собственно поп-музыку (не всегда с негативным отношением). Например песни Селин Дион придется назвать "попсовыми в плохом смысле". Образ крутого мачо эксплуатируется в рэпе и R'n'B, поэтому назвать их попсовыми тоже "не поднимается" рука - придется уточнять что именно имидж попсовый, и тут опять нестыковка - попсовый имидж это скорее имидж поп-певца.

Мне кажется что точного аналога в русском языке для всех приведенных случаев нет (вульгарный, пошлый и т.д. хороши, но тоже несленговые). Но если обратиться к альтернативным толкованиям слова cheesy, многие пишут о чрезмерной сентиментальности музыки, кино и т.п.
В этом случае можно подобрать слова с гастрономическим оттенком (*слащавый, приторный*, опять же *безвкусный*). Еще одно слово, хорошо передающее идею форсированной сентиментальности - *слезоточивый* (подчеркивает идею насильных слез).

Если говорить о спорте или каких-то других победах то можно использовать выражение *"с душком"* передав идею "сырного запаха".

Comment: Слезоточивый - это уж что-то из арсенала спецслужб. Тогда уж "слезливый".

Comment: @Anixx Слезливый - тоже хороший вариант. Что касается "слезоточивый", этого контекста в словарях нет. Но гугл выдает на "слезоточивый фильм" 1260000 результатов. Например заголовок новостей: "Англичане назвали самый слезоточивый фильм".

Comment: Об актере можно сказать что он "переигрывает" - показывает что-то гипертрофированно: "правдоподобность на высоте, актеры не переигрывают (странно, где у нас в стране смогли найти столько актеров, которые играют так, что им веришь)".

Answer (score 3):

Мне потребовалось несколько лет в Америке чтобы понять, что это слово обозначает и как его использовать. Для меня это точно было понятием без аналога в русском языке. Чем больше я встречаю таких слов, тем лучше я понимаю особенности той и другой культуры.

"Показушный" и "нарочитый" describe something artificial, non-authentic, which is not the same as cheesiness. Someone or something can be genuinely cheesy. It certainly has to do with lack of taste, so "безвкусный" is somewhat close, but "cheesy" is some specific. It refers to a very particular kind of lack of taste, roughly --- overdoing something, and not to a lack of taste in general.

Comment: Overdoing is "натужный" I think. Hovever it cannot be applied directly to a person or person's looks.

Answer (score 2):

"Показушный" or "нарочитый" seems to me to be pretty close equivalents to meaning described in quoted entry.

Comment: In the same vein: "наиграный"

Answer (score 2):

пошлый - прекрасное слово, которое отражает многие оттенки cheesy: cheap, unpleasant, or blatantly inauthentic

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is *низкосортный*, *безвкусный*, *пошлый*. *Попсовый* might be the best equivalent, but it is highly colloquial.

Like Quassnoi says in his comment, there may be better alternatives in certain contexts.

Comment: Actually *попсовый* is a good word. "Cheesy" is not that high style as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is *вульгарный*, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Прямого аналога конечно же нет, но мне кажется что такое слово как `биспантовый` (именно так биспантовый, хотя это в какой то мере образующее от беспонтовый) будет очень близко к 'сильным' вариантам cheesy.

> Биспантовая лирика Селин Дион...
>   Биспантовый мужик с золотой цепью на волосатой груди и дешевыми понтами:)
>   Забитые фразы биспантовы по своему определению...
>   Биспантовый фильм, с наматыванием соплей на кулак...

Еще раз подчеркну, все фразы с этим словом очень эмоциональны с сугубо сленговые. А вот слово `cheesy` можно встретить в окружениях более близких к обычному языку.

Comment: А 'бис'-то откуда берётся? По-моему, это против грамматики. Если и используется, то в чрезвычайно узких кругах.

Comment: Думаю что 'бис' идет из 'падонковского' интернет сленга, но точно не уверен. И я так подчеркнул что это сленг, так же как и cheesy, ну еще есть слово стремный, на мой вкус не такое сильное. Опять же, прямого перевода нет, и быть не может, все зависит от контекста и в какой то мере настроения/отношения говорящего к тому где он использует cheesy.

Comment: @sergzach, черезвычайно круглых кругах - что это?

Answer (score -1):

Я бы сказала "лажовый". Беспонтовый тоже звучит хорошо, тут главное подчеркнуть, что и у них это слово сленговое и не стоит искать аналог в литературной лексике :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a slang word i think "пафосный" will do too

Comment: May do for Celine Dion, but not for gangsta rap singer.